# BroadcastReceiver not getting set

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth

I am trying to Discover bluetooth devices and for some reason, I keep getting the illegal exception that receiver was never registered.

I was able to discover devices before on a Fragment. This was making the UI wait for the discovery process to be completed before it does anything so I tried to move this code to an AsyncTask. Same problem. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help/suggestions are welcome.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

private View rootView;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;
private TextView lockStatus;
private TextView connectionToLock;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> availableDevices;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;


public HomeFragment(){};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleLock);
    lockStatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lockStatus);
    connectionToLock = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.connectionToLock);
    availableDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    lockStatus.setText("Lock Status: DEFAULT");
    connectionToLock.setText("Searching for BT Devices ...");

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    btDeviceDiscovery();
    return rootView;
}

private void btDeviceDiscovery(){
    //assume bt is turned on for now
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

    getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, filter);
    Log.i("BT Discovery", "Devices found: "+availableDevices.size());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("onDestroy", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("onReceive", "Finally Called");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        connectionToLock.setText("Found Devices :- \n");

        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.i("onReceive", "\n  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
            availableDevices.add(device);
            connectionToLock.append(device.getName()+ " \n");
        } else {
            connectionToLock.setText("No Bluetooth Devices in range.");
        }

    }

};
```

}

And the stacktrace:

```
02-05 15:17:45.227: W/System.err(11086): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.naftal.easylock.ui.fragment.HomeFragment$1@4259a7b8
02-05 15:17:45.227: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:667)
02-05 15:17:45.227: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1743)
02-05 15:17:45.227: W/System.err(11086):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:475)
02-05 15:17:45.227: W/System.err(11086):    at com.naftal.easylock.ui.fragment.HomeFragment.onDestroy(HomeFragment.java:69)
02-05 15:17:45.227: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:1908)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1180)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:639)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-05 15:17:45.237: W/System.err(11086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-05 15:17:45.247: W/System.err(11086):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where's the stacktrace?

Comment: Added Stacktrace. It simply tells me receiver was never registered; but I do. And I cant explain why its doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're receiving an `Intent` prior to being your `BroadcastReceiver` registered. You call a method that registers a receiver, but in that lapse of time until it gets to the registering process there might be an `Intent` that was received by the receiver, but it was not registered yet.

**---- EDIT ----**

There's another idea: You might be calling `unregisterReceiver()` when it was already unregistered, or basically when your `onDestroy()` method is called before you register your receiver. So it could be based on handling your Fragment, try debugging when is it destroyed and then also debug whether you've called `registerReceiver()` prior to that.

Comment: So what would u suggest I do? Call registerReceiver after every filter.addAction()?

Comment: You were right. onDestroy is called before I get to register.  onDestroy is called, then my code attempts to set the receiver. the onReceive method is never called as a result. I am not sure how to solve this though.

Comment: To tell the truth, I haven't played around quite much with `Fragment`s to advice you, but I'd start trying to determine **why** does this happen when you don't expect it.

Comment: The problem was: I didnt call bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery.. So there was never any need to call the receiver. I feel so dumb. Thanx for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register it in yout onCreate() method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, filter);
}
```

If the broadcast are only used in your app you should use [LocalBoradcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), because these broadcasts do not leave your app.

Hope this helps.